# Github Cv_parser-pdfminer bugs

Tags: python, pdfminer

I need to use a python cv_parser in my project .
I have found one on Github,
[Github/cv-parser](https://github.com/Impactstory/cv-parser), so i downloaded it and i have open it with Pycharm.

When i opened the project with **pycharm 2017.3.4**  it demand to install [the required pakages](https://github.com/Impactstory/cv-parser/blob/master/requirements.txt) , so i have downloaded  and installed them with

```
 python setup.py install
```

for each one.

But , a package named pdfminer still have a problem after installing it;

this is what the console return after compiling :

```
 File "C:/Users/GeeksData/Desktop/cv-parser-master/parsecv.py", line 14, in   
<module>
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFParser, PDFDocument
ImportError: cannot import name PDFParser
```

Answer (score 0):

**cv-parser** seems a bit old (last updated 5 years ago) so maybe it used an old version of **pdfminer**.

Now there is no **PDFParser** class in pdfminer.pdfdocument (look up the code on Github), but this class is found in pdfminer.pdfparser.

So I think you have two solutions:

1. Revert to an older version of pdfminer
2. Correct all import lines in cv-parser source code